# VSCode ignoring results of some tests and not showing tests passes percentage

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm trying to create a test for a specific method in my application however while the test passes it's not recognized in the VSCode testing extension.

```py
class Test_TestSendDataController(TestCase):

    def test_geochat_sending(self):
        self.client_sock = socket.socket
        self.client_sock.send = mock.MagicMock(return_value = None)
        self.clientInformationQueue = {"testuid": self.client_sock}

        processed_cot = RawCoT()
        processed_cot.xmlString = "testString"
        processed_cot.modelObject = Event.GeoChat()
        processed_cot.modelObject.detail._chat.chatgrp.uid1 = "testuid"
        
        queue = Queue()
        queue.put = mock.MagicMock(return_value=None)
        
        SendDataController().geochat_sending(self.clientInformationQueue, processed_cot, None, queue)
        self.client_sock.send.assert_called_with(processed_cot.xmlString)
        queue.put.assert_called_once_with(processed_cot)
        assert(True, True)

    def test_other(self):
        assert(False, True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What's the result of executing it separately？

Comment: I have the same issue, has this been resolved by anybody?